# Simplify query spanning multiple objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to filter human query based on which departments the requesting user manages.

Ando (example Human) manages three depts. I want to return all humans in those three departments.

Humans can have multiple contracts. Each contract attaches the human to a department:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
human = models.ForeignKey(Human, related_name='contracts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
department = models.ForeignKey(ShowDepartment, related_name='contracts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I have below works, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to make this query.

```
output_humans = []
depts = self.request.user.human_profile.departments_managed()
for d in depts:
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(department=d)
    for c in contracts:
        if c.human not in output_humans:
            output_humans.append(c.human)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double underscores (`__`) to look *through* a reference (like a `ForeignKey`).

Here y9ou are interested in `Human`s, so we can query with:

```
output_humans = Human.objects.filter(contracts__department__in=depts).distinct()
```

We thus can omit the loops (over `depts` and `contracts`) as well as the `Contract` query.

We thus require `distinct()` (as in not returning the *same* `Human` multiple times) for which at least one of their `Contract`s is in a `Department` in the `depts`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Makes sense and I'll be using it plenty more.